# How to create tree based query from same table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i want to create one tree based data in my html view from mysql.
I have one table `salary_slip` there 2 columns `pay_month` and `pay_year`.

data is like this:

```
pay_month      pay_year

February         2014
march            2014
January          2015
February         2015
April            2015
may              2015
June             2015
January          2016
march            2016
December         2016
```

So now i want to create tree view for the same.so, if user will click on 2016(pay_year) onclick this all data in pay_month in front of 2016 should be display in tree format and same for the all.

My current query is:

```
select 
    PAY_MONTH,
    PAY_YEAR 
from 
    india_salary_slip_details 
where 
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 34 
group by 
    pay_year
```

By this i got my data:
but i can only see each year's first month only.
please provide me with better query so i can get my result.

image for the same:[current data from my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykgkA.png)

Comment: Remove group by from your query.

Comment: when you do use group by, you can't use where. You need to use having instead of where

Answer (score 2):

A major part of your problem comes from the use of [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), which is used for, well, grouping.

MySQL has different handling of `GROUP BY` than other DBMS' that require all non-aggregate fields to be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL give you enough rope with which to hang yourself (so to speak), which is why you didn't get an error for what is clearly not an intended use of `GROUP BY`.

Depending on how your front end is handling the data, you have a few options.

Option 1) Have it load (ordered) and use the output loop to determine the change in year.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    PAY_MONTH,
    PAY_YEAR 
FROM 
    india_salary_slip_details 
WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 34 
ORDER BY 
    pay_year,
    pay_month -- we want it ordered by year, then month, though this will be alphabetical due to the data type
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$year = NULL;
foreach ($result as $row) { // Assuming your result is stored as $result
   if ($row['PAY_YEAR'] !== $year) {
       // Print the year in the left column so to speak, perhaps create a sublist, etc
       // Set the year 
       $year = $row['PAY_YEAR'];
   }
   // Add month
   // Do something with $row['PAY_MONTH'], perhaps add it to a sublist, again, depends on front end handling.
}
```

Option 2) Have it load the years, then the next level asynchronously.

SQL Query to get years:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PAY_YEAR 
FROM 
    india_salary_slip_details 
WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 34 
ORDER BY
    PAY_YEAR
```

SQL Query to get months given a year:

```
SELECT 
    PAY_MONTH
FROM 
    india_salary_slip_details 
WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 34 
    AND PAY_YEAR = (Whatever the year is)
ORDER BY 
    PAY_MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your group by, you just want to order by year :

```
SELECT PAY_MONTH, PAY_YEAR, FROM india_salary_slip_details WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 34
ORDER BY PAY_YEAR
```

Comment: thanks for help bro but I don't want to display this kind of data.please see my image so u will get understand what I want exactly